# Single responsibility of class and method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is an abstarct class Layer:

```
export abstract class Layer {
    protected layers: any[] = [];
    abstract get(): Promise<Layer[]>;
}
```

Concrete class:

```
export class CommonLayers extends Layer {
    async get(): Promise<Layer[]> {

    if (!hasRole('admin')) return;
   
    /* items belows could be loaded from server, now it is empty array  

    this.layers.push({
      title: "Title",
      items: [],
      count: 3,
    });

    return this.layers;
  }
}
```

Using:

```
async getLayers(): Promise<any[]> {
    // let thematicLayers = await new ThematicLayers();
    let customLayers = await new CommonLayers();
    return [...thematicLayers, ...customLayers];
}
```

I dislike this part of code:

```
this.layers.push({
          title: "Title",
          items: [],
          count: 3,
        });
    
return this.layers;
```

This method does a few things.

1. Checks if user has admin role
2. Gets data from response if there is
3. Prepares data
4. Sets data to `this.layers`
5. Returns `this.layers`

I think this method has a lot responsibilities. So when programmer calls the method `get()` he assumes it just returns data.
And it look not readable!

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method that fetches the data from the server. That requires a check if the user is an admin (note this should really be happening on the *back* end, but whatever), and there is *no reason* not to return the fetched data. I don't see a problem here, *as far as it goes*.

The problem is that you are correct that using `Array.prototype.push` in an async function or `.then` callback is a code smell and you don't provide any way to get at the data other than to access the property synchronously (which will expose you to all sorts of timing bugs) or call the method that fetches from the server (unnecessary http calls).

There really isn't any way to square this circle, I would just say that you should stay async all the way:

```
class Foo {
  // this should be a specific type rather than any
  protected layers: Promise<any[]> = Promise.resolve([])

  // I strongly recommend picking a method name other than 'get'
  async get(): Promise<any[]> {
    if (!hasRole('admin')) return [];
    const response = await fetch(someURL);
    this.layers = response.json();
    return this.layers;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4MwVwOwYwFwJYHsrABYEMDOAlJAbAU2AAoAPALmCzgCcEoBzASmAG8AoUUWwuCWqjoRCAbi6gAvhJAzgMfNizAAYkiTs5IAA60kcQvEIATYIoCehWlioAFPQFsEWQgB4MUcwG0AugD5gAF5geyQnFwA6XiwCADdCEl9WAHpk4Dg0Z2o0JAh8UwAjYgxqbUMEMAQYdPMy4FoMDKt0zFQPcy1gbHNYYEY+EmY7R2c3dt8AtmBU4ABJajoURnxzesMwh0IoU20qgGsGRi7gTYykUygMTeB9NGaMjz6+TpAK0gBCTFwCBIByDGMTigv2YrF4-EEwF84m43BgKBoayw2gRxGCGAA7hgEHBwHwYGgSL8YpsAKo4AAyIJhsJAGWcEQsVmUwWiKKgkQAVjEoIMabTwQIhJksIyMJZrPypHJpEA)

This is less convenient for callers, but there isn't necessarily a robust way around it.

What I *would* split out into a second (or more) method is if you do any *logic* on the frontend with the returned data. But if all you're doing is fetching it (conditional on being an admin) then I think it's fine.

Comment: So, instead returning array of layers as before you return promise of layers? As I know async already wraps code in promise, so are you sure in `protected layers: Promise<any[]> = Promise.resolve([])`?

Comment: This does not work: `this.layers = response.json();`

Comment: And this `if (!hasRole('admin')) return [];` I cat not return array it must be promise

Comment: @asad async functions automatically wrap their returns with a promise, so you can just return the empty array. What do you mean "doesn't work"? Works fine in the link in my answer. Can you link to a playground with an error?

Comment: Sorry need to check it

Comment: Could you help me, I want to add response data to specific object: `{id:number, items: response}` and return it

Comment: So, I need to await response then add reponse to object and return